# iPad youtube iframe embed pwa opens in youtube app?

Tags: ios, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api, progressive-web-apps

On iPad iOS 9.3.5 (may be reproducible on other versions), when our React app is added to the device homescreen as a progressing web app (PWA), clicking a video clip link opens a div with an embedded youtube link in an iframe, to render the video clip within the PWA.

Here is the `iframe` code:

```
<iframe width="300"
        height="200" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/IprmiOa2zH8?autoplay=1&amp;playsinline=1"
        frameBorder="0"
        allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

If the youtube app is not installed on the iPad:

- Everything works as expected, when clicking the view video link, a div is visible with the embedded youtube clip ready to play and plays within the PWA.

**If the youtube app is installed on the device (issue occurs)**:

- When clicking the video link, it opens the youtube app, and plays the video there instead. How can we keep the experience in the PWA the whole time, without redirecting to the youtube app if it’s installed?

Note: If accessing the web app via url, instead of the homescreen PWA, the iframe opens within our web app url in safari mobile and plays there, just as expected. The issue only occurs when the video is to open from the PWA while the device has the youtube app installed.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47740/can-i-make-mobile-safari-open-youtube-links-in-the-browser) which suggested to untick the Youtube button in your iPad settings. You may also check this [blog](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/03/01/tip-opening-youtube-videos-in-safari-instead-of-mobile-app/) and see if it helps.

Comment: @abielita I don't have a youtube button there, checked the blog but it works in safari mobile browser, just not when it's a standalone pwa. Works on iPhone PWA fine as well, it's just the iPad where it really want to open it in the youtube app instead of within the parent app.